# How to correctly handle dependencies of static libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I have a project LibA, which is a static library and uses a third party library Lib3. Project LibA builds and executes just fine.

I have another project Exe, which is an executable and uses  LibA. This compiles, but the linker doesn't find the functions from Lib3, which are used in LibA only.

Things I have tried:

- adding the location of Lib3 to the Libary Directories paths in project Exe (the same way as Lib3 is referenced in LibA)
- adding the location of Lib3 to the Additional Library Directories of the linker
- copying the Lib3 *.lib files to the output folder of project LibA (which thus contains the LibA *.lib file)

No matter what I try I still get `LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol`. Only if I in LibA remove the code that actually calls into Lib3 I'm able to compile and link project Exe properly.

How to correctly handle dependencies of static libraries?

Edit: Some code to clarify:

LibA contains LibA.h and LibA.cpp:

LibA.h:

```
class LibA {
    void doSomething();
}
```

LibA.cpp:

```
#include "LibA.h"
#include "Lib3.h"

void LibA::doSomething() {
    //call stuff in Lib3.h
}
```

Exe.cpp:

```
#include "LibA.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   LibA a = new LibA();
   a.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Have you added in your `Exe` project paths to the `Lib3` library? I think dependencies are not "inherited", so when linking the `Exe`, the compiler should know the paths to `Lib3`, even if it's not used explicitly (but I may be wrong, that's why this is a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Yes, I added the path to the Lib3 library in Exe. Same problem.

Comment: Have you, also, added the name of the library `Lib3`? Not only the path?

Comment: Well, in the Visual Studio settings I can only add the directories that contain the libraries. Doing this is sufficient for LibA to link to Lib3

Answer (score 0):

Try using Visual Studio's `dumpbin` to see if lib3.lib has your needed functions exported. 
If you don't, you will need to declare your functions in `lib3.h` with `__declspec(dllexport)`, to make them visible to other modules that try to link to your library.

Comment: I can link to Lib3 from my LibA just fine. The problem only arises if I link from Exe to LibA, which in turn links to Lib3